# jquery configuration error: readyList.promise is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I just copy the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

to my JSP page I am seeing following error while debugging through firebug

**TypeError: readyList.promise is not a function**

Also all the jquery code is not getting executed.

Can someone suggest something pls?

Funny thing is when I use jquery-1.6.4 I am getting below error

**TypeError: jQuery(...)[original] is not a function**

Comment: What *other* Javascript is included in the page? And in which script is that error being caught?

Comment: There are few other plain javascript functions before this script tag. I am seeing this error in firebug while loading the page itself.

Comment: Don't you have a stacktrace showing where the error is ? Just to mention: sometimes it can help to use another tool (the JS console of latest Firefoxs is excellent, and Chrome is not bad too).

Comment: There is no stacktrace I can see in firebug or JS console. It is directly showing this error which is happening at line no 943 in jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: @Sandeep: (How) did you resolve your question? Although there's some months in between - the one answer below seems to correctly address the root of the problem. I think it should be accepted...

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error on a page where an earlier (non-jQuery) script had defined `Object.prototype.extend`, so when `jQuery` tried to call `jQuery.extend` (inside the definition of `jQuery.Deferred`, which is the constructor for `readyList`) it was overridden by the non-jQuery definition. This caused `readyList` not to inherit the `promise` method, which caused the error.

For example, the following HTML recreates the "TypeError: readyList.promise is not a function" error in the Error console:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Object.prototype.extend = function(){
      console.log('Object.prototype.extend', this, arguments);
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i ++) {
        var object = arguments[ i ];
        for ( var property in object ) {
          try {
            if (  !this[ property ] &&
                  object.hasOwnProperty( property ) )
              this[ property ] = object[ property ];
          } catch( e ){}
        }
      }
      return this;
    };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(the overriding is weird: `jQuery.extend` is defined, then called on an object literal to extend jQuery itself.  During this, the original `jQuery.extend` finds the object literal's `extend` property (which refers to `Object.prototype.extend`), and happily uses that to set `jQuery`'s `extend` property, overwriting itself).

It's possible that your error could be caused by the same thing.

To fix it, try including a small script before you include jQuery to just remove any existing definition of `Object.prototype.extend` and see if that clears up the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  delete Object.prototype.extend;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```